# An error occurred while running the specified code generator: "Cannot The length is less than zero." ("parameter "length")"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When add new scaffolded item the error message is

> An error occurred while running the specified code generator:
> The length is less than zero." ("parameter "length")

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VirHT.png)

The Ecommerce `DbContext` code is:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project.Areas.Products.Models.ProjectClasses;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace Project.ECommerceDbContext
{
    public class ECommerce : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
       public ECommerce(DbContextOptions<ECommerce> options) : base(options) { }

        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=DESKTOP-KJE6SRJ;Initial Catalog=ECommerce;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        {
            //Hppen error when inherited from identityDbcontext
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            new Product_Properties().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Product>());
            new Category_Properties().Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<Category>());
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to Solution Explorer -> right click on Areas folder -> Add
-> new schaffolded item -> Identity -> Add -> check "Override all files" -> add DBcontext -> add -> then I get this error

Comment: it's either an internal scaffolder bug, or the error message is unclear and you are doing something wrong. there are several possibilities as to why the error could be happening, but the first thing that caught my eye is that you are already extending `IdentityDbContext` in your current context. why is that? have you already scaffolded before?

Comment: perhaps try changing extended class to `DbContext` and see if it helps. Scaffolder will change it back anyway.

Comment: if nothing else works, just let scaffolder create a new empty context for you. it really doesnt matter, and its only asking for your context so it can change what class it is extending (it just changes `DbContext` to `IdentityDbContext`, and as `IdentityDbContext` is already extending `DbContext` it will be fine, and this way identity entities will be included in your migrations. this is why it wants to know your current context). so u can just let it create an empty context and delete it after you are done scaffolding UI, as long as your actual context is properly extending IdentityDbContext.

Comment: `ECommerce : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` seems good. also, I suggest overriding all files while you can. it can get buggy again later and may not let you scaffold again, so you might as well get all UI views at once while it works.

Comment: Can you tell us which version of the code generator you are using? Also check the class definition to make sure that the length of its properties is greater than 0.